# Libgdx How to get SFX to fade out?

Tags: java, audio, time, libgdx, volume

I have a marching sound file which I play once a specific event occurs, but the issue comes down to having the file fade out in a specified amount of time before being stopped when the volume reaches 0. This project is for Desktop.

```
Sound marching = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("sounds/test.wav"));
```

The first attempt I had at this was scheduling a task through the Timer:

```
final long mId = marching.play(1f, 1f, 0);
for (float i = 1; i > 0; i -= 0.01) {
    Timer.schedule(new Task() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                marching.setVolume(mId, i);
            }
    }, 0.3f);
}
marching.stop();
```

This, however seemed to invoke marching#stop before marching#setVolume

I decided to take another apporach:

```
float volume = 1;
final long mId = marching.play(volume, 1f, 0), startTime = TimeUtils                        .millis();
while (volume > 0) {
    if (TimeUtils.millis() - startTime % 300 == 0) marching.setVolume(mId, volume -= 0.1);
}
marching.stop();
```

I thought that this would reduce the volume based on the amount of time allotted, yet it only made the program freeze.

Is there a straightforward way of fading SFX audio out or some manner of setting frequent sleeps so that I can lower the volume iteratively?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to put this in the `render` method:

```
float FACTOR = 10; // The bigger the factor, the faster the fade-out will be
float mVolume = 1;
boolean mIsPlaying = true;

public void render(float delta) {
    // ...
    if (mIsPlaying) {
        mVolume -= delta * FACTOR;
        if (mVolume > 0) {
            marching.setVolume(mId, mVolume);
        }
        else {
            marching.stop(mId);
            mIsPlaying = false;
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: **WARNING!!!** To those reading this in the future: while this seems elegant, there's a problem in LibGDX where setting the volume to be negative *can* cause LibGDX to be unable to allocate the audio buffer, not allowing you to load further music into that variable. It may come up as `com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Unable to allocate audio buffers`. [You can read more about it here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/libgdx/issues/1502). I just spent 3 hours trying to figure out why my program kept crashing due to this error, and it was because the volume ended up going negative.

Answer (score 1):

First solution is wrong, I rewrote it for you:

```
final long mId = marching.play(1f, 1f, 0);

    Timer.schedule(new Task() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (float i = 1; i > 0; i -= 0.01) 
               {
                      marching.setVolume(mId, i);
                      if(i<=0)
                         marching.stop();
               }
            }
    }, 0.3f);
```

Second solution freeze your app because you are calling it in the main thread and not in a async task!

However using the render task is not a good idea. You should detach render task from game loop task. Read that: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html. Logic of your game should run at the same speed in all machine. Cannot be limited by rendering issue/slow problem.

Comment: I tried implementing your solution, but it seems that it waits the whole delay before invoking what's inside of run(). This results in it playing the sound for 0.3 seconds before abruptly finishing.

Comment: " that it waits the whole delay before invoking what's inside of run()" this is correct. Try to change the step factor to 0.001.

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of the run() method if the delay is 0.001?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html                void schedule(TimerTask task, Date time)
Schedules the specified task for execution at the specified time.

Answer (score 1):

I find this works much better than using a loop.

I set `MUSIC_FADE_STEP` to 0.01f (i.e adjust volume by 1% each time through).

I adjust fadeRate (in seconds) as required. 0.01f works well as a starting point.

```
Timer.schedule(new Timer.Task() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (music.getVolume() >= MUSIC_FADE_STEP)
            music.setVolume(music.getVolume()-MUSIC_FADE_STEP);
        else {
            music.stop();
            this.cancel();
        }
    }
}, 0f, fadeRate);
```